# XSLT 1.0 - 3-level grouping different hierarchy

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I need to create a 3-level grouping in PDF output, using an engine supporting XSLT1.0, and XML below:

```
<root>
    <Products name="product01">
        <Instruments name="ins01">
            <Bill name="bill123">
                <Notes>some text</Notes>
            </Bill>
            <Bill name="bill123">
                <Notes>some text</Notes>
            </Bill>
        </Instruments>
        <Instruments name="ins02"/>
        <Instruments name="ins01">
            <Bill name="bill456">
                <Notes>some text</Notes>
            </Bill>
        </Instruments>
    </Products>
    <Products name="product02">
        <Instruments name="ins01"/>
        <Instruments name="ins02">
            <Bill name="bill456">
                <Notes>some text</Notes>
            </Bill>
            <Bill name="bill123">
                <Notes>some text</Notes>
            </Bill>
        </Instruments>
        <Instruments name="ins02">
            <Bill name="bill456">
                <Notes>some text</Notes>
            </Bill>
        </Instruments>
    </Products>
</root>
```

Here is a sample of what I've done so far in my template:

```
<xsl:key name="groupProducts" match="/root/Products" use="@name"/>
<xsl:key name="groupInstruments" match="/root/Products" use="concat(@name,/Instruments/@name)"/>
<xsl:key name="groupBilling" match="/root/Products" use="concat(@name,/Instruments/@name,/Instruments/Bill/@name)"/>
            <xsl:template name="testing">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/root/Products[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupProducts',@name)[1])]">
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" margin-top="4pt">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <fo:table>
                                                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                                                <fo:table-body>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="/root/Products[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupInstruments',concat(current()/@name,/Instruments/@name))[1])]">
                                                        <fo:table-row>
                                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                                <fo:block color="blue">
                                                                    Instruments: <xsl:value-of select="/Instruments/@name"/></fo:block>
                                                                <fo:block>
                                                                    <fo:table>
                                                                        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                                                                        <fo:table-body>
                                                                            <xsl:for-each select="/root/Products[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupBilling',concat(current()/@name,current()//Instruments/@name,/Instruments/Bill/@name))[1])]">
                                                                                <fo:table-row>
                                                                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                                                                        <fo:block color="green">
                                                                                Billing: <xsl:value-of select="/Instruments/Bill/@name"/>
                                                                            </fo:block>
                                                                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                                                                </fo:table-row>
                                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                                        </fo:table-body>
                                                                    </fo:table>
                                                                </fo:block>
                                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-body>
                                            </fo:table>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:template>
```

I want to group first after Products, then after Instruments, and then after Billing. With above template, is grouping the Products, but then Instruments and Billings are not showing/are not grouped.
I cannot change the XML to have all elements in one line.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think in place of all uses of `/Instruments/@name` you simply want a relative path `Instruments/@name`, the same `Instruments/Bill/@name` instead of `/Instruments/Bill/@name`, to make sense in the context of the XML and the `match` patterns you have. But I guess in the end you want to chance the match pattern as well e.g. `<xsl:key name="groupInstruments" match="/root/Products/Instruments" use="concat(../@name, @name)"/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved it.